# How to select/find data from inner array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How I can extract (find) tags for date 2013-01-14?

```
  db.test1.insert(
    {
    date: Date("2013-01-14"),
    name: "Roma",
    tags: [{Python:14,Ruby:10,C:4}]
    }
    )
```

I tried extract all info for current date, but even this request do not work:
`db.test1.find({date:Date("2013-01-14")})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mongo shell wrap objects of Date type with the ISODate helper but the objects remain of type **[Date](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date)**. So when inserting dates in MongDB, you could use the 
**`ISODate()`** constructor which returns a Date object using the **`ISODate()`** wrapper instead of the **`Date()`** method which returns the current date as a string.

When you query, use the new **`Date()`** constructor which returns a Date object using the ISODate() wrapper to get a date object that you can then use in the query, bearing in mind that JavaScript date objects months are zero-based index thus January has the value 0 in the constructor parameter.

**Inserting**:

```
db.test1.insert({
    "date": ISODate("2013-01-14"),
    "name": "Roma",
    "tags": [
        { "Python": 14, "Ruby": 10, "C": 4 }
     ]
})
```

**Querying**:

```
var myDateObj = new Date(2013, 0, 14) // JavaScript Date object months are zero based index
db.test1.find({ "date": myDateObj }, {"_id": 0, "tags": 1})
```

**Result**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "tags" : [ 
        {
            "Python" : 14,
            "Ruby" : 10,
            "C" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```